# How to see which apps used data connection?

Tags: apps, security, internet

I'm using GPRS for connecting to the web, and I have disabled automatic backups and updates and also blocked most background tasks and all those sort of things... But when I wake up I see my internet charge has finished !

So maybe there is something wrong with the provider or one of my apps is sharing/stealing something.

how can I monitor which app used how much of the network connection?

I'm using WP8/Lumia 920

Comment: Have you considered using an app to track data usage?

Comment: Hi Karancan, have you any suggestion? An app. (Although I guess apps may not have this level of access in WP)

Comment: Try this one: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/counters/dd91f5d5-9cf8-4d1d-8fba-beaa01fafa47

Comment: Your phone has DataSense?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft released their own application called [DataSense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage?signin=true) that allows you to monitor your usage. This is carrier-dependent though so you'll have to check that your provider/country have an app for it (you can search the Marketplace for DataSense on your phone).

If neither of those is good for you, then I'm afraid for the forseeable future you're stuck with managing your account in the browser with your provider (that's what I do and I'm on EE in the UK).

**EDIT: Actually, with the GDR2 firmware update from Nokia, Data Sense is going to be more wide-spread** see [HERE](http://www.wpcentral.com/leaked-images-lumia-925-data-sense-and-more-gdr2):

> In the photos, we can see Data Sense, which is reportedly going more widespread with the GDR2 update

**EDIT 2: After updating  to GRD2, I can confirm that on my Nokia Lumia 920 (on EE in the UK), I now have the DataSense app, hopefully you can receive this too.**

Comment: It depends on the carrier if DataSense is available. The Counters app isn't available for WP8.

Comment: @Aschratt Yeah I already mentioned DataSense being carrier-dependent. Thanks for the heads up on Counters though.

Comment: @Aschratt Looking at todays news, Data Sense might be on it's way to a lot more carriers.